# taxonomy image as background image on node

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, entities, media

I have taxonomy images attached to node that I would to make me background image.
Previously I used the images uploaded to the node as a background image.

This is the code I used to print out the image:

field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']); ?>);">

This what I thought it would be but I keep getting errors
field_departimage[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']['field_image'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']); ?>);">

Here's my array. Field_image is the field name attached to the node that links to the taxonomy

[image: array]

Comment: Please format code as code, and don't use images for text content. Code block is easier to read, easier to copy from, and searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that field_image is not under `target_id` try this:

`field_departimage[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['entity']->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']); ?>);">`

However this not the best way to load field value, you should use [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7)

Comment: No didn't work. Just gave me a white screen

Comment: Just updated my answer, term is loaded as an object not array. give it a another try. again you should use `field_get_items`

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks so much. When I have enough points I will vote you up just need one more  :)

Comment: you are welcome, you can mark it as an accepted answer. You don't need points to do that.